# Custom Case View based on Custom User Object Field

Tags: apex, case, picklist, cross-object

I'm trying to create a custom case formula field so I can create a view that allows someone to view all cases where the case owner belongs to a certain site as defined on their user object in the picklist value "Work_Site__c":

```
Owner:User.Work_Site__c
```

I am receiving the following error:

> Error: Field Work_Site__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are
>   only supported in certain functions.

Are picklists not accessible through formulas or are they not accesible through cross-object formulas?

Any recommended workarounds?

Comment: Picklist are accessible in formula. Have you gone through the documentation around using picklist in formula? A good starting point is trailhead -- https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/advanced_formulas/units/picklist_formulas

Comment: Have you tried the usual trick, wrapping it in `TEXT()`, ie, `TEXT(Owner:User.Work_Site__c)`?

Comment: @battery.cord Perfect! If you want to repost this comment as an answer I will mark it as correct. Do you know why though? I'm assuming this has to do with the type? Like a picklist value is of value type and not a text type?

Comment: Basically, yeah. You have a formula with a TEXT output type, so you can't use a Picklist output, so you need to convert it  to the right format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your picklist value in a `TEXT()` function.

From the documentation:

> Converts a percent, number, date, date/time, or currency type field into text anywhere formulas are used. Also, converts picklist values to text in approval rules, approval step rules, workflow rules, escalation rules, assignment rules, auto-response rules, validation rules, formula fields, field updates, and custom buttons and links.

Your end formula will look like this:

```
TEXT(Owner:User.Work_Site__c)
```